# Are "contains only Xs and Ys" / "only Xs or Ys" ambiguous?

Tags: conjunctions, only

I want to talk about collections where each element may be one of a couple types, either X or Y (independently of others).
If English had parentheses, I could say "contains only (X *or* Y)s".  And that's the logic I used in a computer program.

But in a textual comment explaining the program's goal, I preferred to speak of the whole collection, which is likely to (1) contain a *mix* of Xs *and* Ys, though allowed to (2) contain only Xs, or (3) only Ys.

I originally used "contains only Xs and Ys" wording but was questioned by a colleague why I said "and".
Apparently they read it to mean "must contain some Xs *and* some Ys, and nothing else" — scenario (1) only.
Is "only Xs and Ys" inherently ambiguous between (1)/(2)/(3) vs (1) meanings?

Can I write "contains only Xs or Ys"?
I'm worried that's also inherently ambiguous, could be read as "either only Xs (2) *or* only Ys (3) but not both"?

How about "contains only Xs and/or Ys"?
Is that a good way to capture (1)/(2)/(3) clearly?

Is there a "distributive law" for how to read conjunctions after "only"?

Comment: The starting position is that *only Xs **AND** Ys* is the "natural" way to describe the situation when every item is *either* X or Y (feasibly they're ***all*** Xs or ***all*** Ys; the proportional distribution is irrelevant / unspecified). So if you used *only Xs **OR** Ys*, many people would assume you meant they're EITHER ***all*** Xs or ***all*** Ys - simply because if that *wasn't* what you meant, you'd have probably used AND anyway. But in terms of actual English language, the OR version is inherently ambiguous (there's no scope for ambiguity with the AND version).

Comment: If it's a requirement that every item be either X OR Y, **AND** there must be  at least one of each type, you'd have to use more words to specify the situation.

Comment: There is no requirements of at least one of each type.  Personally I thought "only Xs and Ys" is clear, as you are saying, but a colleague has read it differently .  Even if I turn out to be "correct", I'm interested in suggestions how to word it for less de-facto ambiguity.

Comment: Your colleague's interpretation sounds nonsensical to me. Like I said, *only Xs **and** Ys* simply specifies that every item is either an X or a Y - it's agnostic as to whether they're *all* X or all Y. But assuming your colleagues are effectively your target audience, you'll just have to use as many words as necessary to make sure they don't misunderstand. This isn't about what phrasing is "correct". It's about what your audience will unambiguously *understand*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a logical issue. Using "A or B or both" is an effective usage for dealing with this type of logical difficulty.

But preliminary understandings are needed:
Xs is taken to mean {one or more of X}
Ys is taken to mean {one or more of Y}

only {Xs and Ys} = {one or more X and one or more Y}
*= there are Xs and Ys*
meaning (1)

only {Xs or Ys} = {One or more X} or {one or more Y}
*=there are Xs and no Ys, or there are Ys and no Xs*
meanings (2) or (3)

only {Xs or Ys or both} = {One or more X but no Y} or {one or more Y but no X} or {both}
*= any number (from none upwards) of X and any number (from none upwards) of Y*

The use of "or both" captures the meaning that is missing from usages (1), (2) and (3)

Comment: Delighted to see this accepted and helpful. It really is not a matter of opinion, but one of logic affecting usage (as can often happen).